# Does Mavericks support OpenCL?

Tags: xcode, macos, opencl

I installed the new OS X Mavericks and new Xcode on the "mid 2011" Macbook air.

I run the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898719/some-unexpected-behavior-on-opencl-in-xcode-and-bash), trying to test if the GPU supports OpenCL. But It seems to behave the same it behaved on Mountain Lion. It seems Mavericks doesn't support OpenCL yet.

Answer (score 2):

Mavericks supports OpenCL but your GPU is not compatible (there are no OpenCL drivers for it).

Try running the example with `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU`, Simply set the variable `gpu` to 0;

```
int gpu = 0;
```

[This paper](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-release-notes/#PGDL) says OpenCL Support on Sandy Bridge is limited:

> 3rd Generation Intel® Core™ Processors with the Intel® HD Graphics 4000/2500

Your Macbook Air is equipped with HD Graphics 3000.

Comment: Seriously? my intel gpu doesn't support opencl?

Comment: @0x90 Unfortunately it seems to be the case. There is some confusion about this issue. If I were you I'd look into the matter in more details before giving up.